# Products not showing in homepage 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Installed 1.9.0.1, portuguese-brazil language

Added to homepage:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

When updating attributes of product to visible on Main Website, server doesn't save the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use at top of catelog/product/list.phtml file

```
$collection = $this->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('yourattribute');
```